# Hide scrub bar in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

in my application a video file is loaded using MPMoviePlayerController. I would like to not allow the users seek forward using the scrub bar, I want them to watch the whole video. At the same time I would like to have Play/Pause controls available to him. Can anyone suggest me a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with the standard controls since none of the values of `MPMovieControlStyle` will do it.  You will have to create a separate view with a play/pause button and run `stop` or `play` on your `MPMovePlayerController` instance when the user presses the button.

Comment: +1 for correct official solution.... anything else would be naughty hacks (which is possible but not recommended at all).

Comment: what should i do in case i want all the embedded features of a MPMoviePlayer excluding the seek bar @ironMensan